# State pattern + C++ template

Tags: c++, c++11, state, state-machine

This finds its origin in the following reflection. In their book from 1995, the so-called gang of four (GoF) described the state pattern. What they were actually telling us in their description, is that any object oriented language that implements dynamic polymorphism has an embedded finite state machine (FSM) engine. C++ is such a language, and the example code in the book is written in that language. Why then, do we have to use large frameworks, libraries and tools in order to implement state machines in C++?

I asked myself that question recently for a C++ project where I have the freedom to choose my tools. Since I have long been a supporter of the KISS-principle (keep it simple stupid), my first intention was to just apply the pattern as described in the book.

Basically, the state pattern tells us that the FSM should have a pointer member to a virtual state class, always pointing to a specialization of that class, that represents the current concrete state. It then delegates the events it receives to the state pointer, like this (quoting the book):

```
TCPConnection::ActiveOpen () {
     _state->ActiveOpen(this);
}
```

where TCPConnection is the FSM and ActiveOpen() is an event.

However, the event handlers look like this:

```
void TCPClosed::ActiveOpen (TCPConnection* t) {
     // send SYN, receive SYN, ACK, etc.

     ChangeState(t, TCPEstablished::Instance());
}
```

where TCPClosed and TCPEstablished are concrete states.

Not so neat. I started to wonder if templates couldn't help me to parametrize the target state in `ChangeState()`. If the state had both a reference to the FSM and the ability to transform itself as a result of a transition, surely I would get a much simpler and cleaner syntax.

### Example FSM

Let's assume that I have the following silly state machine to implement (made with ArgoUML, if anybody is curious).

[image: silly state machine]

[Silly state machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wij86.png)

It is silly, but it contains the features that, in my experience, are necessary in a state machine implementation:

1. Entry, exit and transition actions.
2. Guards (conditional transitions).
3. Event parameters (a free event signature would be nice).
4. Composite states (states that contain sub-states).
5. Orthogonal states (also called and-states, which are semantically equivalent to separate simultaneous FSMs, but it is sometimes necessary to run them in the same class). E.g. LevelState and DirectionState are orthogonal states in the example.
6. Access to FSM members (variables or functions).

The UML has a lot more than that, but I am not convinced that the rest is strictly necessary in the FSM implementation. After all, we have the rest of the programming language for that...

### What I want is all you get

The kind of event handler I want is this:

```
void Machine::Red::paint(Machine::Color color)
{
     if (color == BLUE)
          change<Blue>();
}
```

where Machine is my FSM, Red the state, paint() the event, color an event parameter and Blue the target state for the transition. But you knew all that, it's in the diagram.

As the code below testifies (public domain, use it as you wish, but don't blame me - compiles with g++ 4.6, C++11 switched on), I have managed to implement the state machine depicted above, in such a simple syntax, with the help of a 40-line state template that I have called `GenericState` (genericstate.h, the rest is the state machine code):

1. Entry and exit actions can be defined at any state level. Transition actions are programmed as regular instructions in the event handlers before the actual state transitions. There is, however, a difference with the UML in the order of execution: transition actions, exit actions (old state), entry actions (new state). The UML has exit, transition actions, entry. But mine is the same order as Miro Samek's model (http://www.state-machine.com/) - i.e. it is not uncommon and there is nothing wrong with it as long as it is consistent.
2. Guards are regular "if" or "switch" statements in event handlers.
3. Event parameters are regular event handler arguments. The event handler signature is free (and clutter-free).
4. Composite states are implemented by applying the same model recursively. In the sate machine above, the state "Left" contains a `ColorState` virtual state that can be "Red" or "Blue". However, when going from "Left" to "Right", the exit action from the current color will not be executed (contrary to the UML semantics, but not a practical problem I believe).
5. Orthogonal states are managed by letting the FSM have several virtual state members instead of just one (`LevelState` and `DirectionState` in `Machine` in the example).
6. Access to the FSM members is given to all states through the FSM reference "m" (e.g. `m.changedColor()`).

### Questions:

- Any known similar implementation?
- Any obvious bug or hazard?
- Any obvious potential for improvement (performance, type safety in template use, etc.)?
- It looks like I have unintentionally applied the so-called "curiously recurring template pattern". Do you recognize any other pattern in my implementation? Any other pattern related comment?
- My implementation has a low RAM footprint (only one state instantiated at a time per FSM instance and orthogonal region) but a certain runtime cost: every state transition will incur the creation of a state instance and the destruction of another one on the heap. Comments about that?
- A reader of an earlier version commented off-line that my states were not flyweight as described by GoF. This basically means that my state instances cannot be shared between several state machine instances. I agree. I would not get such a simple syntax otherwise. I think the trade off was worth it. Comments?

**genericstate.h**

```
#ifndef GENERICSTATE_H
#define GENERICSTATE_H

#include <memory>

template <class State>
using StateRef = std::unique_ptr<State>;

template <typename StateMachine, class State>
class GenericState
{
public:
    explicit GenericState(StateMachine &m, StateRef<State> &state) :
        m(m), state(state) {}

    template <class ConcreteState>
    static void init(StateMachine &m, StateRef<State> &state) {
        state = StateRef<State>(new ConcreteState(m, state));
        state->entry();
    }

protected:
    template <class ConcreteState>
    void change() {
        exit();
        init<ConcreteState>(m, state);
    }

    void reenter() {
        exit();
        entry();
    }

private:
    virtual void entry() {}
    virtual void exit() {}

protected:
    StateMachine &m;

private:
    StateRef<State> &state;
};

#endif // GENERICSTATE_H
```

**machine.h**

```
#ifndef MACHINE_H
#define MACHINE_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "genericstate.h"

class Machine
{
public:
    Machine() {}
    ~Machine() {}
    void start();

public:
   enum Color {
       BLUE,
       RED
   };

public:
   void liftUp() { levelState->liftUp(); }
   void bringDown() { levelState->bringDown(); }
   void paint(Color color) { directionState->paint(color); }
   void turnRight() { directionState->turnRight(); }
   void turnLeft() { directionState->turnLeft(); }

private:
    static void print(const std::string &str) { std::cout << str << std::endl; }

    static void unhandledEvent() { print("unhandled event"); }
    void changedColor() { print("changed color"); }

private:
    struct LevelState : public GenericState<Machine, LevelState> {
        using GenericState::GenericState;
        virtual void liftUp() { unhandledEvent(); }
        virtual void bringDown() { unhandledEvent(); }
    };
    StateRef<LevelState> levelState;

    struct High : public LevelState {
        using LevelState::LevelState;
        void entry() { print("entering High"); }
        void liftUp() { print("already High"); }
        void bringDown() { change<Low>(); }
        void exit() { print("leaving High"); }
    };

    struct Low : public LevelState {
        using LevelState::LevelState;
        void entry() { print("entering Low"); }
        void liftUp() { change<High>(); }
        void bringDown() { print("already Low"); }
        void exit() { print("leaving Low"); }
    };

private:
    struct ColorState : public GenericState<Machine, ColorState> {
        using GenericState::GenericState;
        virtual void paint(Color color) { (void)color; unhandledEvent(); }
    };

    struct Red : public ColorState {
        using ColorState::ColorState;
        void entry() { m.changedColor(); }
        void paint(Color color);
    };

    struct Blue : public ColorState {
        using ColorState::ColorState;
        void entry() { m.changedColor(); }
        void paint(Color color);
    };

private:
    struct DirectionState : public GenericState<Machine, DirectionState> {
        using GenericState::GenericState;
        virtual void paint(Color color) { (void)color; unhandledEvent(); }
        virtual void turnRight() { unhandledEvent(); }
        virtual void turnLeft() { unhandledEvent(); }
    };
    StateRef<DirectionState> directionState;

    struct Left : public DirectionState {
        using DirectionState::DirectionState;
        void entry() { ColorState::init<Red>(m, colorState); }
        void paint(Color color) { colorState->paint(color); }
        void turnRight() { change<Right>(); }
    private:
        StateRef<ColorState> colorState;
    };

    struct Right : public DirectionState {
        using DirectionState::DirectionState;
        void turnLeft() { change<Left>(); }
    };
};

#endif // MACHINE_H
```

**machine.cpp**

```
#include "machine.h"

void Machine::start()
{
    LevelState::init<High>(*this, levelState);
    DirectionState::init<Left>(*this, directionState);
}

void Machine::Red::paint(Machine::Color color)
{
     if (color == BLUE) change<Blue>();
     else ColorState::paint(color);
}

void Machine::Blue::paint(Machine::Color color)
{
     if (color == RED) change<Red>();
     else ColorState::paint(color);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "machine.h"

int main()
{
    Machine m;

    m.start();

    m.bringDown();
    m.bringDown();
    m.liftUp();
    m.liftUp();
    m.turnRight();
    m.paint(Machine::BLUE);
    m.turnLeft();
    m.paint(Machine::RED);
    m.paint(Machine::BLUE);

    return 0;
}
```

### Output

> ```
> entering High
> changed color
> leaving High
> entering Low
> already Low
> leaving Low
> entering High
> already High
> unhandled event
> changed color
> unhandled event
> changed color
> ```

Comment: Here is a TM in C++: http://stackoverflow.com/a/275295/14065

Comment: @LokiAstari: I certainly have much more to learn about C++ templates and the whole discussion seems really interesting. Perfect bedtime reading, although it may keep me awake far too late :-)

Comment: Have a look at "Machine Objects" here: http://ehiti.de/machine_objects It's a template library based on the approach you have outlined: state pattern and C++ template programming.

Comment: As an exercise, this [state machine](https://github.com/stateforge/StateBuilder/tree/master/StateBuilderCpp/examples/stdcpp/Silly) has been added as an example to my state machine tools.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have much to say.

Your implementation is similar to the GoF's ([posted here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151002171119/http://codewrangler.home.comcast.net/%7Ecodewrangler/tech_info/patterns_code.html#State)) except that your machine instance is passed by reference to the states' constructors, instead of being passed-in to the states' state-transition methods.

- Advantage: cleaner syntax of the state-transition method
- Disadvantage: state instances can't be flyweights

I wonder whether the following would allow a similarly-clean syntax but allow states to be flyweights:

```
class LevelState {
public:
    virtual LevelState* liftUp() = 0;
    virtual LevelState* bringDown() = 0;
};

class HighLevelState : public LevelState {
public:
    LevelState* liftUp() { print("already High"); return this; }
    LevelState* bringDown() { print("leaving High"); return LowLevelState::enter(); }
    static LevelState* enter() { print("entering High"); return &singleton; }
private:
    static HighLevelState singleton;
};

class Machine
{
public:
    Machine() { levelState = LowLevelState::enter(); }
    ~Machine() {}
   void liftUp() { levelState = levelState->liftUp(); }
   void bringDown() { levelState = levelState->bringDown(); }

private:
   LevelState* levelState;
};
```

This has some of the same advantages as your scheme (clean state methods) but also allows singleton/flyweight states.

Heap operations can be relatively expensive; and I imagine that some state machines ([for example, the tokenizer of a parser](http://www.goldparser.org/doc/templates/tag-dfa-table.htm)) might want to be as fast as possible.

IMO a benefit of your scheme is when the state instances should carry state-specific data. For example, perhaps the TCPEstablished state has [associated data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) which needs to be stored somewhere. If the state is a flyweight then that data must be stored in the machine; but maybe the machine has many states, each with state-specific data, and it's not appropriate for the machine to contain data for the states which it's not in at the moment: in that case you may want state-specific data for the machine in the state instance => state is not a flyweight.

Comment: However, it looks to me that what makes my solution non-flyweight is the reference to the FSM and state reference in the state. Making singletons of concrete states won't help that. In fact, it will in practice make my FSM a singleton, which does not fulfill my need.

Comment: Yes, your solution is incompatible with flyweight states, unless you machine is also a singleton. BTW I noticed that (in your example use case) you hardly use the `m` member of your `GenericState`. GenericState is mostly only using `StateRef<State> &state` i.e. states contain a reference to the `unique_ptr` in which they're contained, so that they can change themselves.

Comment: True about m. It's not supposed to be used in GenericState. It's supposed to be used in concrete states (and is in my example). That why it's protected and not private.

Comment: I have added a section in the text of my question about flyweight and runtime cost.

Comment: @nilo The main time at which you're referring to `m` in a leaf state seems to be in the `void entry() { ColorState::init<Red>(m, colorState); }` method. Could you eliminate that by having a single 'composite' `DirectionAndColorState` whose leaf states are `Right`, `LeftBlue`, and `LeftRed`, perhaps with `Left` as an abstract superclass of `LeftBlue`, and `LeftRed`?

Comment: What I was referring to was Red::entry() { m.changedColor(); }. The point is that the states shall be able to access the state machine members in a seamless manner. Like t->ProcessOctet(o) in the GoF's example. Even if I use it lightly in my example, it plays a central role in the way I want to apply the pattern.

Comment: When it comes to flattening the composite states, I do not want to do that in the general case. Sometimes, the best way to describe a state machine is by using composite states. In that case, I want to be able to express them in a natural way in my code.

Comment: I have also thought about the alternative design where the composite state is a parent class of its sub-states. But that would force the children to forward the events they don't care about to their parent, which is the opposite of the semantics I am using at the top level. Not very consistent, in other words. This is why I have chosen this solution instead.

Comment: @nilo I don't think leaf states need to 'forward events they don't care about' to their superclass. If they don't care about an event then they simply don't override the corresponding virtual function, so that virtual function is only defined/handled in the superclass.

Comment: Correct about not overriding parent state behavior. I knew I had a good argument against that design, but I picked the wrong argument :-) My argument I think was the ability to define orthogonal states lower down in the hierarchy. Left should be able to have simultaneously a TasteState region (Sweet, Sour, etc.) and a ColorState region (Red and Blue). I think applying the model recursively is the best way to achieve that.

Comment: I have removed the section about flyweight and runtime cost in the main question, since I now realize that there is a trivial solution to runtime cost, if I am ready to have one state instance per concrete state in the state machine. I will post it as an answer to my question later on.